# Vala / GTK3 set widget height

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, vala

I'm new to Linux development and Vala/Gtk. I'm trying to learn as much as I can while testing various function.

This time, I tried to create some GUI application and I stuck at setting the height of widget. Looking at valadoc and gnome docs I couldn't find any method to do so.

So for example, if I have two buttons on a horizontal box, how should I resize the `Box()` height?

This is the code I have right now:

```
var hBox = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0);
    hBox.set_spacing(-10);
    hBox.set_homogeneous(true); // Same width of buttons

    // Set margins of maim menu icons
    hBox.set_margin_start(30);
    hBox.set_margin_end(30);
    hBox.set_margin_top(10);

// Top buttons (Main | Notifications)
var btnMain     = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Main");
var btnNotif    = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Notifications");

nixnMain.add(hBox);
hBox.pack_start(btnMain);
hBox.pack_start(btnNotif);
```

I've tried for now several options including `set_margin_bottom()`, `get_request_mode()` `and size_allocate()`, also `get_preffered_size()` and several others from docs page.

Also, how can I specify the widget "class" for example, if my CSS is like bellow, how do I specify button to have class buttonMain?

```
#buttonMain {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Image provided
Using `hBox.set_margin_bottom(Screen.height() + 50);` I got the result as in image bellow but I want height of grey buttons to be smaller.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSMDc.png)

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of what you want and what you get? For adding a class, that's done via the widget's associated GtkStyleContext.

Comment: I've edited the post. Please, take a look now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to set the height of a widget directly. You never know when the user might have a different font size set (e.g., for accessible technology), and your height will turn out to be wrong. Instead, use the `hexpand`/`halign`/`vexpand`/`valign`/`margin-top`/`margin-bottom`/`margin-right`/`margin-left` properties, or the widget's container's `border-width` or spacing properties, or use the padding properties in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to set alignment for a widget which you add to Gtk.Box

My example:

```
using Gtk;

void main (string [] argv) {
    Gtk.init (ref argv);

    var window = new Window ();
    window.border_width = 18;
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

    var hBox = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 12);

    // Top buttons (Main | Notifications)
    var btnMain     = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Main");
    btnMain.set_valign (Gtk.Align.START);
    var btnNotif    = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Notifications");
    btnNotif.set_valign (Gtk.Align.START);

    window.add(hBox);
    hBox.pack_start(btnMain, false, false, 0);
    hBox.pack_start(btnNotif, false, false, 0);

    window.show_all ();
    Gtk.main ();
}
```

Comment: Rather than just dumping an example, it would be better if you could explain which of your additions achieve the result the OP wants, and how they function. This does nothing to explain what `Align.START` does, how it differs from the default, and what the added parameters to `pack_start()` do.